# Analysis service connection closed by remote host (Azure SQL Database)

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, ssas

While trying to load the FACT table (~15M Rows) in Analysis Service from a Azure SQL Database, I always get this error after one hour:

> Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.);An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. The exception was raised by the IDataReader interface.

I can't seem find the setting to change the timeout Azure SQL Server... Does anybody know where I can find this?

Comment: We solved this issue by partitioning the data while importing.

Comment: Loading the data in batches may also do the trick specially when the tier of the Azure SQL Database is not Premium.

Comment: There is an ExternalCommandTimeout server property that defaults to 3600 seconds (1 hour). Is that when it failed? I would have expected the error to say “timeout”. Since it didn’t maybe just a network glitch??

Comment: See if there are any errors in the event log of the database: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-event-log-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current

Answer (score 0):

It can be that timeout is set on SSAS side rather than Azure SQL Database?

If you are using modern "Get Data experience (Power Query)" take a look on this thread:

[SSAS tabular model timeout raised during processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49011023/ssas-tabular-model-timeout-raised-during-processing)

To check this, open your model source code by clicking on Model.bim and then F7 and search for keyword "timeout".

The target is to find something like this:

```
"options": {
          "commandTimeout": "PT1H"
        },
```

or

```
Source = Sql.Database("serverName.database.windows.net","databaseName",
[CommandTimeout=#duration(0, 2, 0, 0)])
```

Comment: Where can I find the code for individual Partition queries? I can't seem to find it...

Comment: I don't think this is applicable for me

Comment: I don't have "options" in the source code. Should I add it myself?

Comment: Do you have any mention of "timeout"   in the source code? if no, then problem is not in the Analysis Services...